# Primefaces gmap component editing

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'd like to add vertical line in to gmap component like http://www.highcharts.com/demo/spline-plot-Bands but i don't know even how to start

Comment: I think the link is broken. Furthermore I would advice you to ask a specific question. It will increase your chance for good answers.

Comment: What have you done so far?